# Matplotlib pyplot options as dict or any format

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, matplotlib

How can I import matplotlib pyplot options as dict?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(1,100,100)
plt.plot(x,x*x,color=np.random.rand(3,1),linewidth=2)
```

I would like to covert the last command as:

```
str1={'color':np.random.rand(3,1),'linewidth':2}
plt.plot(x,x*x,str1)
```

It doesn't have to be a dictionary. Any format will be fine. I hate to have to keep typing, but I also don't want to set it permanently. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
plt.plot(x, x*x, **str1)
```

For more information on the dictionary expansion operator, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769475/230468).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for.